# Why popLast() method in swift array has Complexity: O(n) if the array is bridged

Tags: ios, swift

The discussion states that the popLast() method in swift array has Complexity: O(n) if the array is bridged and other wise the Complexity: O(1). Can we get to know more information with regards to this?

Answer (score 1):

`Array` has copy-on-write semantics, i.e. when an array is mutated, it has to check whether it is the exclusive owner of its storage buffer. If there are other arrays sharing the buffer, the array has to make a copy before it can mutate the buffer.

As to your question: I believe if an array is bridged from `NSMutableArray` (and possibly `NSArray`, I'm not sure), it can't reliably determine if other owners exist on the Objective-C side, so it *always* has to make a copy. In other words, a bridged array is converted into a native Swift array on the first mutation, and that's an O(n) operation.